# Is it possible to setup Teams' URL Preview Service for GitLab authentication?

Tags: url, gitlab, microsoft-teams

We use Teams in our development team and we paste links to GitLab to request Merge Request reviews.

Unfortunately Teams doesn't have permissions to see our private repository so the URL Preview Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-privacy-oce-overview#url-preview-service) shows the link as
[image]

Is there a way to give Teams credentials so we can see a preview of the content?

Cheers.

Comment: No, not possible. Teams loads a preview with no session details.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be possible to give Teams credentials so we can see a preview of the content

Comment: you would have thought teams would not show a preview for any 4xx 5xx status codes (shrug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seems to be possible to give Teams credentials so we can see a preview of the content because
**Teams loads a preview with no session details.**